# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'timing' of undefined

Tags: javascript

**How do I properly do object detection for `window.performance.timing`?**

An unknown version of Chrome being run by Googlebot is spawning the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'timing' of undefined

The only instances of `window.performance.timing` are in the following snippets of code:

```
else if (
window.performance!=undefined
&& window.performance.timing!=undefined
&& window.performance.timing.toJSON!=undefined) {/* etc */}
```

Obviously regardless of my efforts to do object detection Googlebot is somehow still spawning the error message. I can *not* use `try` and `catch` and I have zero instances in my JavaScript error log of this happening in any testable (e.g. Chrome itself) browser, only Googlebot.

Comment: Have you tried taking out the != undefined part, and just doing "else if (window.performance && window.performance.timing && " etc.?

Comment: This code works as expected: https://jsfiddle.net/x3373vm5/ . If `window.performance` is `undefined`, it would not try to access `window.performance.timing`. The error must originate from somewhere else.

Comment: The problem is probably in `/* etc */`. :) The error message usually tells you the line number in your code.

Comment: By the way, if it's a bot - have you tried to check the `window` object?

Comment: @FelixKling - The first line of your jsfiddle sets `window.performance = undefined`... If that line is removed, the test fails - https://jsfiddle.net/v7zvvqoq/1/

Comment: @dana: Not sure what you mean with "the test fails". The point of my comment was that **if** `window.performance` is `undefined`, then one would not get the error message `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'timing' of undefined`. I.e. the OP couldn't possibly observe the mentioned error with that code.

Comment: @FelixKling - Ya, I am not sure how this is being observed either.  My point is there is a subtle difference between setting a variable to `undefined` and not declaring it at all.

Comment: @dana: But this is about *properties*. For `window.performance!=undefined` there is no difference whether the property was explicitly set to `undefined` or doesn't exist.

Comment: Well, this sheds some light on things for me - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance/timing - I don't think I have an answer, but apparently there is an API for measuring browser load times?

Comment: @dana http://caniuse.com/#search=performance and the HTML5rocks article looks simple enough. I don't use frameworks so I don't have to worry about performance myself. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Try this way.

```
else if (
window.performance
&& window.performance.timing
&& window.performance.timing.toJSON) {/* etc */}
```

And as I know, you should use !== instead of !=

Comment: Can you also provide an explanation for why you think this solves the OP's problem? "Try this way" is not really useful information.

Comment: I can't cause I don't know exactly why but my js developer friends always does it so. May be you may check and explain it here..

Comment: No offense, but if you don't know what the problem is / could be, you should probably not write an answer.

Answer (score 0):

If `window.performance`is undefined the if statement will still check the other two expressions. If there is no `window.performance` it can't check for `window.performance.timing`.

At least that's what I am guessing. I would try to nest the if statements:

```js
if(window.performance != undefined) {
  if(window.performance.timing != undefined) {
    if(window.performance.timing.toJSON != undefined) {
      /* etc */
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: *"If window.performanceis undefined the if statement will still check the other two expressions."* No it won't. Your code is equivalent to theirs.

Comment: I didn't down-vote this, was having dinner. This would be a good method of trial and error (I can pass parameters to my own error reporting function at each level). Got a bit of work to do.

Answer (score -1):

What if `window.performance` is `null`? I bet you would get the same error message.

That's why the canonical way to check objects existence is:

`if (window.performance && window.performance.whatever && ...) ...`

Comment: *"What if window.performance is null? I bet you would get the same error message."* No. The error message would be `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'bar' of null`. But even if the value was `null`, `window.performance != undefined` will take care of `undefined` and `null` (because loose comparison).